# Improve granularity of tag votes on profile page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

On the *Tags* section of the profile page you see the exact number of votes received until you reach 1000, at this point it is displayed as *1k* and won't change to *2k* until 1500 votes is reached.  Can this be enhanced so that it increments every hundred votes (*1k*, *1.1k*, etc) just as it is displayed on the *Top Users* pages?

Comment: *#HighRepProblems* =P

Comment: I agree with your proposal; you have seen that there is a tool-tip that shows the exact number of answer upvotes, right?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I have seen the `tool-tip` which is good, would be nice to get that info at a glance.  It also seems wrong to display 1500 votes as 2k.

Answer (score 1):

Partially (because only for top tags) implemented in the [new update of profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244238/profile-page-makeover-part-3-the-prototype-returns):

[image]

(e.g. [Jeff Atwood's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tt=profile), which I used to take the screenshot).

Other scores you can see by going to the ["tags" tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=tags&tt=activity) and hovering over tag score.