# Profile Page Makeover, Part 3: the Prototype returns

Tags: discussion, design, profile-page, feedback

#### Update

We have done a bunch of work following your feedback - just look at all those [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tags on the different answers here!

The top suggestion was to do something about the badge visualization - we have listened and completely redesigned that piece - check out the new and improved badge visualization, on the profile page.

In the next few weeks we will preview further profile changes here on MSE - mostly to the activity page and following feedback and rework on those, the new profile page will go live to the rest of the network (6-8 weeks, give or take).

---

You may recall [this thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231112/profile-page-makeover-part-2-the-prototype) - our profile page makeover prototype, the reloaded user page. We posted a prototype *6 months ago* and got a lot of feedback. Since then, generations of dinosaurs were born, fell in love, had families and were eventually killed by a comet.  Or climate change, or maybe texting and driving or some nonsense like that.

We picked up work again after a couple months of avoiding it ([one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243680/when-will-the-reloaded-profile-be-back) or [two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272047/why-is-the-new-reloaded-profile-page-no-longer-available) of you noticed...) and started cleaning up some of the rough edges. We are looking to get this *right* and the change isn't urgent, so we are taking our time on it. We want to have something that is clearly better than the current page.

#### What is all this about again?

The user profile page was trying to address two fairly different use cases:

- What is most valuable and useful when you want to see what **someone else** is all about.
- What you should see when looking at **your own** profile.

Because it was trying to solve both problems in one place, it was decent at both, but not great at either, and it probably was overall more optimized for the "looking at my own profile" use case.

#### So, here's what's happening

If you go to your profile on MSE right now, you'll see it now has two tabs in the top left:

[image]

The "Profile" page is your new public profile. It's what everyone will see by default when they click your picture at the bottom of a post or find you in the [users](/users) list. It should communicate what you know and what you've done.

The "Activity" page is intended to be your own personal dashboard, stuff that isn't necessarily of interest to others but that you want to see when visiting your own profile. *Right now* it's just the old profile page, but we'll be tackling that next and asking for feedback here on how to make it more useful.

See for example the [Activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/138231/balusc?tt=activity) and [Profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/138231/balusc?tt=profile) pages of BalusC - the former shows you his overall activity on the site, the latter showcases him.

#### Some of the things we changed based on your feedback:

**User info section**:

[image: old user info]

[image: new user info]

We also added a new "people helped" counter based on the views your questions and answers have gotten. This is essentially a sum of views of your questions, and answers that fall within the following criteria: accepted, have a score of 5 or more, have more than 20% of total score of all answers on a question or are within the top 3 answers by score. No deleted posts are counted.

**Tags**:

[image: old tags]

[image: new tags]

And some other tweaks and visual updates we can't quite remember - you can see [the old version here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgN0H.png).

Unfortunately the very popular request to [make the badges interactive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231112/profile-page-makeover-part-2-the-prototype/231129#231129) didn't *quite* make it in -- but we may still come back to this later.

#### Feedback

We are looking for your feedback before this goes out to the rest of the network - what's broken? What's missing from the new page? What needs a bit of polish?

Comment: Is there a plan to allow users to see the activity page by default even for other users? This is something I'd really prefer on sites where I'm a moderator.

Comment: @Mad - not at this time, but that's why we are taking feedback :)

Comment: @cVplZ - I will. It is not that complex, but has a bunch of different clauses. Stay tuned.

Comment: Leaving "by default" aside, are you planning to keep "Activity"  visible to other users, or will it be converted to a private page? My evaluation of the profile prototype depends on whether it's one of two things we can see, or the only thing.

Comment: @Raff - the activity page will be visible to all. It is, after all, what the old user page was. All that info is already  public, why change that?

Comment: Here's some links for the pages, which will automatically adjust based off of who is signed in: [profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tt=profile), [activity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tt=activity).

Comment: I still think all the repeating icons for badges is just hideous and looks silly. There has got to be something better you can do with that space.

Comment: I want to see how it looks on my SO profile.

Comment: @animuson: I would guess, that’s what the interactive badges are intended to do. But without them, I agree.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft It's hard to see how one could interact with 1000+ badges on some profiles. They would take a while to load (and those are the most viewed profiles, too).

Comment: What's with that sleek-looking search box in the screenshot?

Comment: @tbodt - not sure what you mean. I don't see a search box in any of the screenshots here.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft - I appreciate that. Trying to keep this to a working list of items.

Comment: Very sad the animated badges didn't make it :(

Comment: Would be great if the images in this question weren't hosted on the reasonably commonly blocked imgur.  ;^)

Comment: @ruffin - they are hosted on the subdomain `i.stack.imgur.com`, which is specifically for Stack Exchange usage.

Comment: @Oded Sure, but parts of the [DoD](http://www.defense.gov/), eg, still block the whole domain. If you can move the US gov't (or any large corp) quicker than I can, I'd appreciate the help. ;) It's a shame the images aren't [at least potentially] "on" SE so that I didn't have to hope a lone voice arguing rationally with the US could be persuasive and everything, instead, "just worked". Rational nuance !== practical usability, unf. Thx though.

Comment: I have to say, I liked the rep and badges where they were :P

Comment: Would it be possible to apply this to other network sites, perhaps on an opt-in basis like other websites tend to do when making design changes. I don't really have an expansive profile on Meta, so it makes it really hard to offer any meaningful feedback about the design. Though, it does serve to slightly shame me for not being more involved on Meta ;).

Comment: @ChrisPratt - it will be rolled out to the rest of the network, but not via an opt-in basis. Once we are happy with it here, that is.

Comment: Well, I was only speaking in a development-stage sense. I assumed the changes would go network-wide once everything was good to go, but only applying something like this to Meta makes it difficult for people who use other network sites heavily, just not Meta to make meaningful input when it's still in a state of flux. Not a huge deal either way, I guess. I can see the argument that if you want to be involved with things like this then you should be more involved with Meta in general.

Comment: Looks clean, for what it's worth, though some of that may just be from my relatively empty view ;).

Comment: @Christian - as I said in my comment - we will be looking at improving the visualization. I did not say we have already done so, but that we have a work item to address it.

Comment: @Chris - you can also look at profiles of other people here to get a feel for how it looks for different people :)

Comment: I really don't see the point of this. With the sole exception of the "Top network posts" box and the silly "X people helped" number, there is no information on the "profile" page that isn't already on the "activity" page. The profile page is just a version of the activity page that takes more space to display less info. If you justify the existence of the profile page by redesigning (removing information from) the activity page, then you have two semi-unuseful pages instead of one useful page. If you don't remove information from the activity page, then the profile page is simply superfluous.

Comment: @Boann - this is the first part of a whole set of changes. The activity page will change - the information on the profile page will not be redundant. The pages exist to serve two different purposes (others looking at your profile, you looking at your profile).

Comment: This is very messy and it looks as if SE is trying to nullify the division of the network into distinct sites and communities and throw everything into a big messy melting pot instead. It reminds me of Quora, and the new profile is equally unuseful to the ones on Quora because you have a hard time to retrieve your own stuff.

Comment: I like it. It provides useful information in an interesting way. Don't listen to the people who can't help but resist change. When will we see this network wide?

Comment: The new badge treatment is *much* better -- thanks!

Answer (score 105):

The whole piece was redesigned, so making [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). Let me know if you feel that's off-base.

(expanding on [animuson's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244238/profile-page-makeover-part-3-the-prototype-returns/244275#comment798282_244238))

The rows of dots illustrating badges is silly. It doesn't convey any useful information. It doesn't even visually convey the number of badges, since the size of the dots is adjusted depending on the number of badges. This picture (with both screenshots scaled at 80% to fit on the same line on the desktop site) suggests that I (left) have more silver and bronze badges than Jeff (right), if I go by badge-covered area!

> [image: Gilles's badges]
>   [image: Jeff Atwood's badges]

Drop that and use the space for something useful, such as having a column for recent badges and one for the most notable badges (suggestion by [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio)). Or one for the counts and one for the notable badges. Or drop the column formatting altogether.

Comment: I agree that this is silly and wasted space.  Instead of dedicating a column to tag badges (which will be sparse on some sites and for many users), I'd rather see either recent badges or the ones *I* think are most notable.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Tag badges are quite reflected in the tags section just above, after all.

Comment: +1 Yes please. In prototype part 2 [I made a similar request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231286/152515). I want to see recent badges, and I don't find this display useful or effective at conveying what it's supposed to convey: the quantity of badges is not conveyed well by the diagram when the resizing makes 1,118 badges look far less significant than 692.

Comment: (referencing to left and right images fails on the Android app, the second image is below the first one, I suggest you use *1* and *2*, *a* or *b*, etc.)

Comment: @A.L Good point, but the visual comparison requires that the images are side to side, so I'm a bit stuck (I could paste the images together but it's too much effort). This answer is written in a left-to-right language, so I consider it transparent that the left image is the first one and the right image is the second one.

Comment: @Gilles : it's hard to see that there is 2 images since their background is white (like the answer background). Can you please try to add `> ` in front of the 2 images? The blockquote will add a yellowish background, it may help to see the borders of the 2 images

Comment: If we switch the dots to a column of badges (we should), then I think it would be cool if we could choose which badges we wanted to have on display.  For example, I am much more proud of some of my bronze badges in particularly obscure topics than I am of some of my gold badges.

Answer (score 74):

1. <strike>FOR SVG (or just divs with enough `border-radius`, as it is done with badges on the left - they are not SVGs, but SVG is just a short word to use on the pic :); but on other sites where the shape of badges is [more complex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244238/profile-page-makeover-part-3-the-prototype-returns/244245#comment798314_244245), I think that SVGs would be used rather than CSSing divs)! And no excess borders please.</strike>

In a sense, this is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), since the whole thing changed and is all lovely and zoomable.

> [image]

2. <strike>Wow, great number! What does it mean?</strike>

   Already mentioned in other answers here and already has a [dedicated meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244261/what-is-people-helped-and-why-does-it-exist-at-all).

   > [image]
3. <strike>Someone is trying to eat the right part of badges...</strike> (this is fixed)

   > [image]
4. <strike>(using the profile of [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tt=profile))</strike>

   - The biggest place is not for the tag with highest score
   - Only the tag in the biggest slot has a badge displayed, even if the user earned badges for other tags
   - There is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) in the last slot, however more scoring tags are omitted ([stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) or [reputation](/questions/tagged/reputation) or [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) - their score is 1k)

   All these points have now been addressed (next build).

   > [image]
5. <strike>Clicking "My Logins" from "Profile" tab doesn't open login window. But it still works in "Activity" tab.</strike> (this is fixed)

   > [image]
6. <strike>If user don't have top network posts, the section tells us that he doesn't have... *hot* network posts?</strike> (updated to top)

   > [image]
7. <strike>Uset info fields (website, location, age) are good margined only in the profile of currently logged user:</strike>

   > [image]

   <strike>For all other users, the margins are bad:</strike>

   > [image]

   Given the low impact and that we are working on a redesign for the activity page, this will not be fixed. [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Comment: It is planned, but we though that for a _preview_ this was OK.

Comment: Why are your free hand circles green? USE RED!!

Comment: 47K people helped... ???? What?? exactly

Comment: No need for SVG, a div with border-radius is enough.

Comment: @bjb568 Yeah, didn't think about it, silly me :D Of course div with border radius will be enough.

Comment: Seems like the help is the cumulative amount of views that questions or answers you have provided have been viewed.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough Which is a meaningless stat IMHO. At any case, introduction of such a number should be discussed separately from the profile page makeover.

Comment: @bjb568 But what about sites that have custom badge icons? They won't be able to get away with rounded <div>s..

Comment: @gand Sure, but now it is just on MSE :)

Comment: Oh. Well, until then I suppose. BTW, nice hand drawn lines ;) (no joke, they really are nice) Did you use a tablet or some fancy nice software (or both)?

Comment: @gand First img is from my SGS5, drawn in "Draw!", other are drawn on my computer (using mouse) with http://pixlr.com/editor :)

Comment: @gandalf3 Those should be at least 3x.

Comment: @bjb568 Huh? What should be? (and 3x what?) I'm afraid I don't understand..

Comment: @gandalf3 "custom badge icons" on other sites; bjb is a fan of high-density display resolution.

Comment: @bjb wait. I don't get what you say. How can it be anything-x at all? Svg doesn't seem to have resolution as such...

Comment: @nicael If they were too lazy to make SVGs (or concerned about support or whatever), they could still make raster graphics that look good at at least 3x.

Comment: @bjb568: No, they couldn’t. When it comes to displaying stuff on pixel scales, you have to design stuff to the pixel or use some special rendering technology [like your computer uses for text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinting). Coincidentally, I have an example for this at hand: Here are my proof-of-priniciple sketches for Academia’s mortarboard badges: [1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MbyOB.png), [2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zAfzB.png). In the first one, I messed up the pixel grid (in a relatively benign way, being exactly 50 % off).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Design stuff to the pixel, just make there be more pixels per stuff. Then make the browser render it smaller.

Comment: @bjb568: Then you would get something similar to my first example again. No algorithm is intelligent enough to reduce the sice of a picture such that the result is designed to the pixel.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft So? You can't deal with pixels on the web.

Comment: @Raff now in [separate answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244308), feel free to downvote :D

Answer (score 63):

The top network posts should show whether they're questions or answers. Like this:

> [image]

Just because I think it would be nice to know at a glance.

Comment: Not to mention, as you have an example of in your image, sometimes your top votes are from self-answered questions.

Comment: Even better, split it into two lists. "Top Network Questions," and "Top Network Answers."

Comment: @jimirings That's already covered on the full profile; i think it's good not to take up *that* much space on the site-specific profile.

Comment: @Scimonster It wouldn't have to take up more space. We could do the top 3 questions and the top 3 answers, fill the same amount of space, and only show one less post than we are now. When you say "full profile," I'm not sure if you mean the new activity tab or the network profile, but the network profile is a whole different beast and the activity tab only shows top Q's and A's for that specific site, not network-wide.

Comment: @jimirings I meant network profile.

Comment: @BlueRaja Of course you can't have an answer without a question, but still, wouldn't you like to know if your tops are questions or answers? :)

Answer (score 58):

Make these thingies links to their respective pages, please:

> [image: moar linky needed]

---

> These UI elements have a specific job, adding links would detract from that.

Hrm? That really doesn't make much sense. Adding links does not necessarily require a change in appearance, correct? (Aside from underlining on hover, or something along those lines.) So if the only effect is purely functional and not visual, how would that "detract from their job?"

In any case, I expect them to be clickable, and you don't gain anything by keeping them unclickable (other than making it that much harder to find what you're looking for).

Comment: Obviously, the first thing should link to the list of people you helped... or failing that, to some blog post explaining "written once, read many times" effect... or better yet, discarded altogether.

Comment: Can we have a gold badge if we helped 100k people? I think that is the least for our efforts.

Comment: @juergend:  Let's use Jon Skeet as a benchmark instead.  I'd say his number would be closer to 750K, but I'm thinking that 250K would be reasonable for gold instead of 100K.

Comment: @Makoto: A SEDE query could tell how many would get the badge on those numbers to make it sound. It sure could be a bigger number instead of 100k. But I would not say Jon Skeet is a good comparison to the rest of the users.

Comment: Yeah, that might be the better way to go.  Shog's got 1.4M helped in his profile, and we know that's both an outlier and only on MSE.

Comment: @Makoto Atwood got 2.6m arbitrary PH points.

Comment: @Raff:  I might make this a formal request, but this is why I'm saying that 100K for a gold badge might be too low.  I'd need more info to determine that, though.

Comment: @Makoto [Shog9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) has 1.4 million people helped on Meta.SE. I'm sure Jon Skeet's number on SO would likely be at least 7.5 million if not like 40 million with that same algorithm.

Comment: We won't be adding links everywhere - in particular when there are links to these pages already present. These UI elements have a specific job, adding links would detract from that.

Comment: As for "People Helped" - there is a [separate discussion thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244261/what-is-people-helped-and-why-does-it-exist-at-all) for that.

Comment: @Oded Hrm? That really doesn't make much sense. Adding links does not necessarily require a change in appearance, correct? (Aside from underlining on hover, or something along those lines.) So if the only effect is purely functional and not visual, how would that "detract from their job?" In any case, I expect them to be clickable, and you don't gain anything by keeping them unclickable (other than making it that much harder to find what you're looking for).

Comment: @Oded So StackExchange was wrong for ages by having **three** identical links to a lot of stuff in the user profile? They have a specific job, I agree: to be at hand so that I can easily reach whatever stuff. I can't see any harm in making stuff clickable.

Comment: @Oded in the current profile page design, **all** headers are links. You'll be taking away a feature that is used by many.

Comment: @Sha - I am keeping the discussion open and will be bringing it up internally, as I am not convinced either way.

Comment: Thanks @Oded, keep us updated.

Answer (score 43):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - after discussing internally, we decided to decline this request. We understand that for some avatars the display is not optimal, but that will be true for just about any design with some avatars.

The grey background that spans the top half of the avatar box is somewhat distracting. It’s barely visible but sufficiently visible to catch someone’s eye.

It looks particularly irritating for avatars with a white background, which does not only include some selected custom avatars such as mine but also many Identicon avatars:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Clearly, these avatars should use transparent background. ;)

Comment: @Raphael: Yes, they should and [I wish they could](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210132/255554). However, even then, that grey box is distracting.

Comment: We have sites with dark themes, which have the exact same background issue already (see [scifi.se]). Declining this one.

Comment: @Oded: If you are referring to avatars in general, you might answer this to the [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210132/255554), I linked. If you are referring to transparency in Identicon avatars, you might have a point (though it’s only the Meta of Science Fiction & Fantasy, where this would be an issue). (If you are referring to the answer, I have no idea what you are talking about. )

Comment: This is mostly about avatars in general. But in regards to the background - that's here to stay.

Comment: Contrast point taken- I'll see what our designers think. I'm also wondering if a lightweight outline makes sense to address the issue where a white background "bleeds" into the white wrapper.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft - Not sure what the problem there is - Gravatar and SE support transparent avatars - [see my answer to that question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244435/33051)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I stand slightly corrected - this is only not an issue if you use Gravatar rather than the image upload feature.

Comment: Some of us have avatars where transparency isn't so easy to create. The burden should rest with SE simply making the avatar expand to the full space of the container rather than forcing us to add transparency to our own images so that they look right. Our avatars were here first.

Comment: @Oded: Please note that, while I used some avatars, where the background looks particularly bad, to illustrate my request, my main point is that the background looks bad with every avatar – which was not addressed in your statement of declining.

Answer (score 39):

I don't like having the top network posts directly on the site profile. Voting varies a lot between sites, so this is likely to highlight questions in a different subject matter. I post on a variety of sites, and I know everything is public, but if (hypothetical example) I show my [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) profile to someone, I don't want them to think too much about my [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) questions from when I spent 48 hours walled in after the latest blockbuster release.

Comment: We are working on being able to exclude sites from the list.

Comment: @Oded From the network-wide list? But why would I want to show my CS research for gamers? Or from each site individually? You mean I have to configure 128 sites and counting?

Comment: I believe the idea is to have one global exclusion list that will apply to both the communities list and the top network questions list.

Comment: @Gilles So, in essence, you want to be able to [hide connections between accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197600/allow-users-to-hide-connections-between-accounts)?

Comment: @episanty Not really: if I really cared about that I'd use different accounts with different credentials. Rather, I want to not thrust unrelated accounts into the viewer's face. Having them all in my network profile is fine, having them all on my profile on one site isn't so great, having the highly biased view of top-scoring posts is yucky.

Comment: Maybe we could do away with absolute numbers and use a figure relative to the average/median score *on that site* (or even for that tag)? That would not solve the "what interest does the bicycle community have in my Unix answers?" problem but *would* tackel the difference in voting behaviour/scale.

Comment: @Oded, please consider site weighting as Raphael suggests in the prev comment. This doesn't need to be dynamic & IMO should be per-site *not* per-tag. I'm thinking that a query that runs once per day (or even once per week) that computes a scaling factor for each site, that the "top" lists can then factor in, would be enough. Some of my best posts are on small sites where vote counts just won't get the post onto that list, *but* the answer isn't to blanket-exclude my big sites -- those are valuable too, but shouldn't dominate. In a way it's similar to the HNQ problem & can be solved similarly.

Comment: Agree that this is a problem: we had a user leave LEGO Answers because his highly rated answer was appearing above his SO answers on some network lists :(.

Comment: @Raphael I've made a separate post for weighting the sites: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244460/162102

Answer (score 29):

This issue has its own thread now:

[We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/the-new-probably-shouldnt-be-called-people-helped-stat-input-needed)

---

**"people helped"** is a rather misleading term. It helps to boost the ego, but it's really a lie.

Most of the question views will not count as somebody you actually helped. For one, your answer may be number 3 in the list with a score of -3 and really not helping anybody.

It's a nice statistic, but call it "total views of posts" or "post views" for brevity. And add a mouse-over with explanation or a link to a site with details. Because, right now, I am merely speculating as to what it means.

Comment: I don't think answers that are "*number 13 in the list with a score of -3*" are counted in "people helped," because "*answers that fall within the following criteria: accepted, have a score of 5 or more, have more than 20% of total score of all answers on a question or are within the top 3 answers by score*" (from the question)

Comment: @Shokhet: OK, 13 was too far out. I toned it down to "number 3". But I'd like to see a minimum requirement of "non-negative score".

Comment: That makes sense, I agree.

Comment: We'll share the method and get some input on tweaks, but it wouldn't count your example - the current method requires posts to be upvoted and high enough ranked that they likely get seen by a good number of visitors.

Comment: @Jaydles: I trust you'll find a reasonable algorithm.

Comment: Yes. For some users "people annoyed" would be a far more accurate description -- I agree calling it "post views" would more accurately convey what it is.

Comment: This now has a dedicated meta thread: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244261/what-is-people-helped-and-why-does-it-exist-at-all

Answer (score 23):

I want to be allowed to decide which of my badges are notable. You might think that *[Explainer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68258)* is cool, but perhaps I want to showcase one of my silver badges in the top spot instead.

So, feature request: Allow us to choose which badges are notable.

Comment: Wouldn't the most rare badges you've earned *usually* fit the bill?

Comment: @Raphael Sometimes, but not always. And that's the point of this suggestion.

Comment: Note that the profile has essentially nil options now (aside from About Me). There are many more useful options that should come first, *especially* if what you propose is unlikely to be used by many.

Comment: That would be great for questions and answers, too.  I'm really not that excited that my top answer ever is about fractions

Comment: @Raphael And what options did there used to be anyways?

Comment: I know the feeling @AlexanderGruber. My top answer on Code Review was a review of some LOLCODE. Not my finest moment, but it stares everyone right in the face when they visit my profile.

Answer (score 21):

The score for the Top network posts doesn't really stand out. For a few seconds I was wondering why the titles of posts were things like "18 Shortest unmatchable regular expression" and "16 How many Stack Exchange logins should I have?"

In my opinion, it may look better with a slight background, maybe like this:

> [image]

---

<strike>Also, I have a score of -8 in [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). Why is it in my top tags?</strike>

---

Braiam just pointed out that there is a discrepancy between my [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) score on https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/238586/the-guy-with-the-hat?tt=profile

[image]

and the score on https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/238586/the-guy-with-the-hat?tab=tags&tt=activity

> [image]

That's been fixed now.

Comment: Actually you have 3, but yeah, there's something weird going on http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/238586/the-guy-with-the-hat?tab=tags&tt=activity

Comment: Yeah - that tag score doesn't look right. Will investigate.

Comment: It's totaling the question and answer scores together.

Answer (score 20):

This issue has its own thread now:

[We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/the-new-probably-shouldnt-be-called-people-helped-stat-input-needed)

---

## Please call People Helped something else or drop it: that name is disingenuous.

You've explained the way this is calculated, and I've read it:

> We also added a new "people helped" counter based on the views your questions and answers have gotten. This is essentially **a sum of views** of your questions, and answers that fall within the following criteria: accepted, have a score of 5 or more, have more than 20% of total score of all answers on a question or are within the top 3 answers by score. No deleted posts are counted.

The problem is, we all know **full well** that view counts are not remotely correlated to people helped. It pretends all of the following scenarios, which would increase the view count, also signify a new person helped, even though that isn't the case (this list is not exhaustive):

- Someone who happened across the question, determined it wasn't what they were looking for, and left.
- People who were visiting to read, already knew everything written in an answer, agreed with it and considered it helpful, and upvoted that answer.
- Repeat visitors, who aren't looking for an answer to help them. (In 2010, people investigating the views count mechanism found that [the same visitor could increase the view count multiple times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated), if they simply spaced out their visits. If this is still current, I could count for 5 "people helped" myself on a question just revisiting my own answers to edit them further.)
- People visiting to perform moderation, or check that things are okay. (This accounts for *most* times I've added to a view count)

The people who visited and were helped by an answer is only a portion of views. It's also an *indeterminable* portion of the views. (That means we can't [emulate such a number](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244280/152515) accurately either.)

My answer to [Betrayed by my GM; how can I respond?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/29677/betrayed-by-my-gm-how-can-i-respond/29683#29683) is one of my highest-scored, most viewed answers. I'm confident I made a difference to some people, but I don't believe it's accurate to say the views (6595) capture that number. This was an extreme and toxic social situation most viewers will never have to deal with (thankfully). Fewer than that could have learned something, or maybe through a ripple effect a lot more than that number did. But I don't know how many were helped, really, and neither do any of us.

The honest thing to do would be to admit we don't know how many people we help. Views are views. That statistic is more accurately labelled "views on questions you've answered which meet certain criteria" or something else, but "people helped" is not an accurate label. I'm not sure what such a statistic would mean, exactly, but if you display it, please do not label it "people helped". Raff has [suggested in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244238/profile-page-makeover-part-3-the-prototype-returns/244287?noredirect=1#comment798406_244287) the possibility of calling it "total readership", which is one possibility much nearer the mark.

Comment: Related discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244261/what-is-people-helped-and-why-does-it-exist-at-all?noredirect=1#comment798387_244261

Comment: Some form of *total reach of posts* would be more accurate, if the statistics is to stay at all. Or SE could do what they did in tooltips in "[Hot Network List](http://stackexchange.com/)": *this user has been  arbitrarily awarded 145.2k helpfulness points*.

Comment: Also, I suggest moving this to the discussion started by tohecz , since this is not really a design decision but a content decision.

Comment: @Raff I posted it here since it's feedback on the profile page makeover. I considered leaving this as an answer to tohecz's question, but in the past I've left feedback on an announced feature outside the announcement and SE staff asked me to move it to the announcement.

Comment: Okay. Another possible more-honest name would be *Total Readership*.

Comment: @Raff Thanks, I've mentioned that in the conclusion of the answer.

Comment: +1, agreed. One point: "*I could easily count for 5 "people helped" myself just revisiting my own answers to edit them further*" is unlikely; I haven't seen the algorithms, but it's likely that they only count unique IP addresses, so you'd count the same no matter how many times you came back to edit further.

Comment: @Shokhet Added some citation to that. The views mechanism does let the same individual count for multiple views, supposing they simply space out their visits.

Comment: @doppelgreener I see that now. Thanks for clearing that up for me :)

Comment: I agree. When I read "people helped" I thought it votes the total number of upvotes + anonymous feedback. (Which would, of course, underestimate the number of people helped.)

Comment: Suggest calling it "kittens killed".

Comment: How about calling it "dissemination"?

Answer (score 19):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The custom scrollbar here is fancy and all:

[image: scrollbar]

But it's really hard to click since it's so skinny. Could it be embiggened?

---

After taking a look at the CSS:

```
.bio::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 4px;
    background: #f4f4f4;
}

.bio::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #dad7d7;
}
```

It shows up bigger in Firefox because FF doesn't support those pseudo-elements.

Personally, I like the way it looks in Firefox better, so those lines of CSS could just be removed.

Comment: What's your browser/OS? I'm guessing chrome, [it looks fine](http://i.imgur.com/otsXtHY.png) on FF/Linux.

Comment: @terdon Chromium 37.0.2062.120 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Nowadays we don't really click to scroll anymore.

Comment: I click to scroll *sub-page* elements; otherwise my swipe would scroll the whole page.  I'm not seeing a skinny scrollbar on Firefox, by the way.

Comment: @MonicaCellio "It shows up bigger in Firefox because **FF doesn't support those pseudo-elements**"

Comment: @Braiam if you note the timestamps, that information was not in the answer when I made the comment.  Ok, so it sounds like if they keep this I'm going to need to install Stylish on Chrome in order to override that CSS, 'cause what's in that screenshot sure is hard to use.

Comment: @MonicaCellio well, it quite possible that you haven't see it yet, so I was just informing you ;)

Comment: +1 for "embiggened" .....although, honestly, it's not such a big deal if you're on a computer -- I rarely click the scroll bar to scroll *anything*, preferring to scroll with the mouse dial or with two fingers on a touch pad.

Comment: @Shokhet Depends on your usage. There's those like me who use their keyboard for anything that the mouse can't do quicker. Likewise among those that use the mouse, there's people who like their scroll-wheel or middle-click, and those that like having a decent scroll bar they can actually position their mouse over.

Comment: @doppelgreener Yes. For instance, my Mom uses internet a lot, but she doesn't know how to use the scroll wheel (it confuses her, the scroll bar does not).

Comment: Looks like eating some turkey helped poor 'ol skinny.

Comment: @Oded But did he leave any for me? :( (thanks!)

Answer (score 19):

This is much-improved over the previous version.  However, the tags section still has too low a signal-to-real-estate ratio.  Look at all that empty space within the top tag block!  If you want to do some sort of size-based visualization, you could easily get twice as many tags in that same space without it being cluttered.  The current ("activity") version is much more useful to me, showing me ten tags instead of six and in less space.

You've said that the order will be changed to show top tags by score (like on the current page).  That's good; that's less confusing.

I don't particularly need to know if people have badges for their top six tags; I can see the scores, after all, and if I really want to know if there were enough non-CW answers to earn the badge, I can hover and find out.  If the badges don't cost much space then *meh*, but if that's part of why you're spreading things out so much in this view, consider dropping it from here and adding it to the "all tags" page, which favors functionality over aesthetics already, instead.  It'd do no harm, and it might be handy to have one place to scan for "tags this user has answered enough to earn badges".  (This would also address the request elsewhere to call out tag badges in the "badges" section, which is only space well-spent for users who have several of those.  Most don't.)

Answer (score 18):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The text color of the badges on the sites section upsets me:

[image]

The bronze badge text stands out way too much. Make all the badge labels the same colour.

Comment: I think that is the general coloring of high numbers on SO. There are a lot of bronze badges, and because of that the number starts becoming orange-ish.

Comment: @DJDavid98 Nope, it happens even for numbers of badges that are not high [here, I have 43 bronze, less than the 56 gold I have on Arqade](https://i.imgur.com/HhP88gd.png).

Comment: I actually don't see a reason why the numbers would be bold ... ?

Answer (score 16):

**Please weight "top network posts" by site.**

My top network posts section currently looks like this:

[image: 5/7 Workplace]

You'd think, from this list, that I participate mainly on The Workplace with a smattering elsewhere on the network.  But that's not really true; it's just that posts on The Workplace get a lot more votes *overall* than posts on the other communities where I participate.  By local standards some of my Mi Yodeya posts are way more significant than the ones shown here, but we are a small community and those posts are unlikely to ever crack this list.  Ditto Writers, Pets, and <strike>Moderators</strike> Community Building.

This gives a distorted view of my participation.  I would like to see posts here be weighted by some measure of per-site activity that reflects voting (average score/post for the site, maybe).

I'm not suggesting that this be done in real time every time a profile is loaded; that would be way too much load on the servers.  A job that runs once per day (or even once per week) that updates a table of weighting factors would be good enough.  Unlike top posts on the *current* site (where the profile is being viewed), this needn't be completely up to date.

We have another list that has similar issues and is addressed by weighting: hot network questions.  If the raw hotness formula governed what's on that list, SO would dominate and small sites would never get onto the list.  SE therefore introduced a score-reduction algorithm based on how many posts a site already has on that list, which smoothed it out some.  Handling of the HNQ list is what gave me the idea for how we could address a similar problem in another multi-site list.  (I don't know if an algorithm designed for a 100-entry list would work well for a 7-entry list, but that might be worth investigating as a solution here.)

Finally, I understand that the current ordering has always been in place on the network profile, and is what people will see if they click through to that.  I'm not asking to change that; I'm just asking that the "first view" of a user active on many sites with highly-varied voting activity be adjusted to more-accurately portray that user's activity.

(I am *not* asking that users be able to customize this list; I recognize the issues with that.  And anyway, I'd rather have an automated list that does a better job than have to maintain a hand-picked list myself.)

Answer (score 13):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Minor CSS cross browser glitch:

[image]

Can you make sure the gold/silver/bronze badges align with their number in IE11 just as good as they do in Chrome?

Comment: We should just not use IE altogether :P

Comment: And while you're looking at that, correct the tooltips: currently they all say "gold badges".

Answer (score 13):

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

I personally liked the "Apps & Projects" section from the second part, can we have that in?

[image: Freehand Circles FTW]

Comment: You can propose it for SO. It doesn't make sense on any other site (not even on this meta).

Comment: @tohecz A projects section makes sense on a lot of other sites, and was requested to be made globally available. From part 1: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226180 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226242, or from part 2: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231291

Comment: You can always add your apps and projects to the "about me" portion of your profile, customized for particular sites.

Comment: Also to this feedback, +1 yes please! I _really_ want to see the Projects section available. It was a very good idea, and probably one of the most useful sections available.

Comment: I would estimate that this makes sense on fewer sites than it does. Maybe one could have the column as an option, being able to fill it with project URLs (from many services) at your own volition (and even on a per-site basis)?

Comment: This is still planned, we're just trying to split this thing up into pieces to get it out the door. That feature needs a new edit interface so we punted it for now.

Comment: @DavidFullerton `contenteditable="true"` & `if (event.keyCode === 13){ ... }` for the win.

Comment: @DJDavid98 - didn't realize that would also automatically sync it up to your data store. With validation.

Comment: @DavidFullerton please consider the effects on the vast majority of non-SO SE users who won't have anything to put in that space.  Will the space be used for something else or will there just be a vast expanse of nothingness on those profiles?

Comment: @monica You'll get the current side-by-side badge layout if you haven't put in any projects.

Answer (score 11):

I am voting **against** any features such as

- Allowing users to select their "top" badges/questions/answers
- Allowing users to exclude sites from their hot/top networks
- Showing projects (such as github/bitbucket repositories)

As for the first two points, StackExchange is not a [social<sup>1</sup>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65261/is-stack-overflow-a-social-networking-site) [networking<sup>2</sup>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice) site. It is a questions and answers site. Customizing your profile will start to creep into the whole personalization thing, which isn't at all what SE is about.

When I go to a profile, I expect to know exactly what I'm looking at -- top/best badges, top posts/answers, etc. I have a specific set of options lined up *for my own personal use* when I few *another* user's profile. If users can customize exactly what's on their profile, then that guarantee is no longer there causing a UX impediment and possibly confusing me (as a user).

Further, if users can hide their questions/answers from the page (such as when I want to see their *lowest* rated questions/answers, which I do from time to time), then I am now seeing possibly skewed information (this is just an example).

---

As for the third point, you run into several issues here, some of which have already been addressed.

- What dictates which sites we can pull repositories from? Is this something the user is going to have to maintain or allow access to?
- We don't have fields for Twitter, Facebook, or XYZ personal profiles; why have projects? I don't care if a user has 15 `hello-world-xyz-language` repositories, and if they're someone who has an established project, they'll most likely have it linked in their *about me* section. It's wasted space and breaks the current theme of profile fields.
- It's still social network-ey. GitHub is probably as close to a social network as a site could be without capitalizing on being a social network. Let them manage that (nothing against them, of course) - not us.
- Since when has the About Me box ever been less than sufficient for showcasing whatever the user wants to showcase?

---

Just my $0.02.

Comment: However, if users spend more time arranging which of their garbage questions is at the top of their list than asking *more* garbage questions, I'm all for it.

Comment: I agree about the projects, but [disagree](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244238/profile-page-makeover-part-3-the-prototype-returns/244254#244254) about badges.

Comment: You can see the most crap of the user in the Activity supertab, which will be retained. The same for badges, the same for linked accounts. If you "moderate" the site, you're supposed to use that supertab, and not the new default thingy, which is really more like a portfolio.

Answer (score 10):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The 'top x% this time' box is too big, relative to the username.

> [image]

It should be a little smaller, IMO.

Comment: It is now smaller.

Answer (score 9):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Please please please display at least *a littlte* section of reputation, something like this:

> [image]

Comment: This logically belongs on the Activity tab. Users who are not really interested in the vanity page under discussion (like me) will probably use a userscript or site setting to open that tab as default.

Answer (score 8):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There's a redundant percent sign for the tags where this is displayed:

[image: Redundant percent sign]

This could be fixed by putting the percent sign in parentheses after the number of posts in that tag (in a smaller font), for instance.

Comment: or "47% of posts", where the 47% is still big

Comment: Fixed. We removed the trailing %.

Answer (score 8):

The new profile page is somewhat overdeveloped. The use cases for a profile page are (speaking from my own experience), in no particular order:

/me looking at my own page:

- switching to another site or the network-wide profile
- checking my unmarked questions
- checking the posts I flagged - have the mods left me a custom message
- finding out why I have -10 reputation (the user has been deleted)
- looking at my suggested edits - have they been rejected or not

/me looking at others' pages:

- looking at knowledgeable posters' favorite pages to see what gold nuggets are there on a particular site
- checking a user's activity/network scores while doing reviews for spam

Does the new design help those use cases? **NOPE**. It detracts from the established routine, adds unnecessary clicks for common tasks, and showcases nothing in particular. Badges? Top network posts? Pleease. I can always go to a user's network-wide profile to see all that.

#### TL;DR : Please please please do not re-invent the profile pages.

**[Given the number of public beta sites that are waiting for custom themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239464/lets-set-better-expectations-for-how-long-beta-lasts), it is obvious that SE designers' time could be better spent on graduating sites.**

Note: I do understand that adding vanity design elements (aka Facebookization of SE) may lead to users spending more time on SE. Will they spend it answering questions? Unlikely.

Comment: *"Given the number of public beta sites that are waiting for custom themes, it is obvious that SE designers' time could be better spent on graduating sites."* - Now that is a point that is *undenyable*. Hadn't thought about this, but of course, 1 site per 3 months is certainly *not* the way to go. Sorry if that's not congruent with voting best practices, but **+1 for that statement alone** just to make a point!

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It says "Moderator ♦" twice on a mod's profile - once in the top bar, where it is in the activity tab, and once by the username. The link should be by the username.

Also, up in the bar looks like it might be another tab.

[image]

(That's gotta be the worst freehand circle ever.)

Comment: I've seen (and made) waaaay worse free-hand circles

Answer (score 7):

This now has a dedicated meta thread:

[We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/the-new-probably-shouldnt-be-called-people-helped-stat-input-needed)

---

The PH ("People helped") stat is IMHO just another ridiculous number, even more ridiculous than the rep. I do not see a reason why to introduce yet another stat like that.

It doesn't bring any new information to the system. Even if it did: Imagine that someone has rep:PH ratio 1:10 and someone has 1:2 -- what is it telling about that person? IMHO nothing at all.

Moreover, this PH stat is even more sensitive than rep to post being discussed on meta, getting tweeted or featured etc. ... we [are currently facing this problem with rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238420/prevent-questions-on-hot-list-from-being-upvoted-by-casual-visitors-only-rep-is/238757#238757) and if you introduce PH, we'll soon face the problem twice as much.

(As a side note, I believe that introduction of a new stat should be discussed completely separately from design decisions on the profile page.)

PS: As Oded suggested, I created a discussion thread about this feature: **[What is "People helped" and why does it exist at all?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244261/what-is-people-helped-and-why-does-it-exist-at-all)**

Comment: Then why not post a discussion question about it?

Comment: @Oded Well, I thought that such a significant thing would get a thread similar to this one from the Powers.

Comment: @Oded ok, done: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244261/what-is-people-helped-and-why-does-it-exist-at-all

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This was also reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244243/259693), but i wanted to make it official:

Tag scores are now being calculated to include answers and questions, while previously it was just answers.

**This is confusing.**

I've used the tag score feature to see how close i am to tag badges, but now that's all messed up.

Please, either bring back the old way (just answers) or make it easy to see the breakdown (perhaps with a tooltip).

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Please remember my choice in "Top Posts".

No matter what I choose (all,questions,answers/votes,newest), after reloading the page it resets to all/votes.

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Can you make a <s>magenta</s> green sprite for the answers / questions when they are accepted / have an accepted answer so they stand out?

[image]

I also really liked that the word "reputation" was grayed out in the Profile tab under my avatar, where it would appear <s>white</s> black like the reputation count. The new change also colors the entire box, which makes it prettier. Thanks!

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: The posts with an accept have a filled up box, but we can look at the sprites as well.

Comment: @Oded Thanks! I asked for this because the Android app has a colored Q/A sprite.

Comment: Is it only me who finds the Q and A circles indistinguishable at first sight?

Comment: The Q&A icons for accepted posts are now colored.

Answer (score 6):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

[image: fancy hover effect thingy]

Observe: Fancy Hover Effect Thingy™ exists in Exhibit B. Fancy Hover Effect Thingy™ is decidedly absent in Exhibit A.

Could the fancy fadey thingy be implemented if the text overflows the area, even without hovering? That would be much better IMO than what currently exists (ellipses happen, not even at a word break!).

Comment: The fancy thingy is IMHO not fancy at all. I've always considered fading more distracting than standard ellipsis. (Which is fine if you want to distract the reader, but that's not teh case here.)

Comment: Declining. The fade is not appropriate for items that are too long - the ellipsis is a better/correct solution here.

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Tag badges link to general respective section of tag badges (bronze, silver, gold), could they link to specific badges please (discussion bronze tag badge, feature-request bronze tag badge)?

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In my [previous answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244289/266359) (deleted when implemented), I requested a count and score for posts in a tag, to be shown on a mouse hover.

However, I'd like to request a small fix to it: it it's not too much trouble, can those numbers be **shown on a hover over the whole gray box** for the tag, and not only when hovering over the numbers at the end of the box? That would make it a whole lot easier to use, and (for new users) a whole lot easier to discover it.

Answer (score 6):

Many thingz in SE show exact info in popup on hover. Please for *people helped* too?

> [image]

Comment: what's that say? I'm reading "moar [ec]ocact plz"

Comment: @Dop :D It did say "moar exact".

Comment: @Raff improved it a bit :)

Comment: @Doppel ^^^^^^^

Comment: I can read it! hooray :)

Answer (score 6):

I think age also should be displayed in "Profile" tab:

> [image]

Comment: Avoid PII (Personal Identifiable Information); or at least offer consent before displaying. This includes location (USA is better than CA, CA is better than San Francisco, San Francisco is better than 123 FooBa Street, San Francisco), age and so forth. There is no reason folks need to know these kinds of things.  If the terms and conditions state that a user should be older than 18 to participate, and the user accepts it, then its binding. There is no need for Stack Exchange to ask for a birth date.

Comment: It is relevant, especially if that information is displayed publicly without your consent. I'm ok with authenticated users being able to see my age.

Comment: @Werner I misread your comment at first. So wait, do you propose to remove age at all or show it only to logged users? You can post such feature-request there as answer. And btw, "that information is displayed publicly without your consent" - it is not.

Comment: My location is. So my assumption here is that you'd like to add the age to the publicly visible data on the right of a publicly viewed profile.  You didn't exactly specify under what circumstances the age should be displayed.

Comment: What I'm proposing is the ability to give consent as to what personal identifiable information is visible to public users (and search agents). This includes my location. I'll file the feature request as an answer.

Comment: Have you searched your name and age on Google? If my age isn't publicly visible, how does Google know it?

Comment: @Werner Your age is publicly visible.

Comment: On this Meta site it is not displayed publicly (I navigated to my profile with a different browser without logging in); on the StackOverflow it is public. When it comes to PII we should always err on the side of caution.  If only I knew that 10 years ago, if only...

Comment: @bloud aka Werner :D http://i.stack.imgur.com/r7U4C.png age is public on any SE site.

Comment: :) Here's the public view of someone who just visits my profile on the Meta site. http://i.imgur.com/SLd4xz0.png

Comment: And on StackOverflow: http://i.imgur.com/zwSEEhZ.png

Comment: @bloud u realize that I clicked the different tab?

Comment: @bloudraak the current profile page ("activity" in the new scheme) *already* displays your age if you supplied the information.  Including it on this redesigned page wouldn't be a PII leak.

Comment: Its already a PII leak if it contains a combination of personal attributes. The goal is to remove it all together, or provide better means to control its display.

Comment: @bloudraak If you don't want to display it, then remove it from your profile. But since it's already shown in the existing profile, it should be in the new one as well.

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There is no notice in the "Profile" tab if a user is suspended, it just looks like he is 1-rep user.

> [image]

Comment: Well, it's still there in the Activity page. That said... wonder what can cause such a punishment to someone with so much reputation! :/

Comment: @Sha just visit tavern :D Scroll a bit up... He was just suspended because he wanted so.

Comment: This will be there in the next build

Answer (score 5):

Will the Activity super-tab (i.e. the old profile view, sibiling of the “Profile” super-tab which is the new profile view) be retained on other people's profiles in the long term? I think it shouldn't: most of the information is redundant. We already have tabs with subtabs on a user profile, adding supertabs is too much complexity for too little gain.

However, all the information that's present on the old profile would need to be accessible from the new profile. Not everything needs to be directly on the landing page, it would be enough for the landing page to include links to:

- the bounties tab
- the activity tab (the one with optional filtering on posts, suggestions, reviews, etc.) (I use this one a lot)
- vote statistics — I do want to know this about people, but it doesn't need to be on the landing page, it can be a click away (a new statistics tab?)

Comment: The tab will be retained, but will get redesigned. Much (all) of the redundancy will be gone. The idea is to progress slowly with our complete rework of all pages, to ensure nothing is left behind.

Comment: As a moderator I want to see the more complete view of the activity page.  I already have to click through a bunch of different places to do my job sometimes; don't make it even harder by removing "redundant" stuff from that view.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Doesn't apply only to moderators, it applies to those high-rep people who do the moderating as well (based on the community-driven concept).

Comment: @MonicaCellio Were you refering to the new “Activity” super-tab or the existing “activity” tab? I absolutely don't want to lose the existing “activity” tab, but I don't think that was in the plans — and I want it a single click away, not two like it would be with the current proposal.

Comment: I meant what's being called the "activity" page here, which is the fuller, useful profile that we're all used to.  I wouldn't want to lose the "activity" tab either.  Sorry for the confusion.  (Err, maybe they should rename one of those...)

Comment: @MonicaCellio What do you miss on the new page? There's nothing else that I'd want to have there directly, even as a mod; but I do want all the extra data (full activity tab, vote count, etc.) to be reached in a single click.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Hmmm, I think we're still talking at cross-purposes. If you're talking about the existing “activity” tab with the chronological view of nearly everything, then we're in full agreement that it should be retained, and I haven't seen any plan to remove it. But you now seem to be saying you want to keep the top-level “Activity” option, but I don't understand why.

Comment: The "activity" tab on the current profile is essential.  The current profile view, which is behind a new "Activity" supertab, contains information that I want to be readily available that is not present on the newly-designed profile.  So I want that supertab to be there.  Voting activity is one example.

Comment: The new profile is designed to advertise a user to other users.  It loads up the view with stuff from other sites (I probably don't care as a mod on *my* site) and *completely* removes access to votes, bounties, activity, and responses.  It makes tags and badges harder to see.  Look again -- none of the tabs we're used to are present on the new profile, most especially "activity".

Comment: @MonicaCellio Uh? The recent activity list isn't on the main page of the old profile either, it's one click away. Do you really need active bounties on the landing page as opposed to behind one click? Responses don't show up on other people's profiles.

Comment: It's one click away on the current profile.  It's *not reachable at all* from the new one.  And responses *do* show in other people's profiles for *moderators*.  This all started with me saying "don't make my job as moderator harder"; read all of this in that frame.  (And I do want to casually notice if a suspicious user has been getting lots of bounties.  I might never think to click through and look; having it on the main page draws my attention to it.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio It's not reachable, which is why I'm requesting for it to be reachable in one click. I still can't figure out if we're agreeing or disagreeing, I think I'll just drop the matter. Regarding bounties, offered bounties are already behind a click now, so that would be a separate feature request.

Comment: And I'm saying that even if activity were linked on the new page, the new page is harder to use and designed for a different purpose, so keeping the "Activity" version is important.  I don't think I can persuade you so I'll stop trying.

Comment: Another thing from the current profile/new activity page that as a mod I use frequently: the flags history.  Just the numbers (helpful/declined) tells me something, and clicking through tells me more.

Comment: From what I can work out you always land on your own activity super tag, no matter where you started.

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

On the "Activity" page, you could hover over a tag and be told the number of questions, the number of answers, and the total score of each of those. Not so on the new "Profile" page.

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request): **show the number of posts per type and total score for questions/answers when hovering over a tag count on the "Profile" page.**

Answer (score 5):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

WTF is that grayish background doing on the avatar?

[image]

<sub>I slightly darkened the color, so you can see it better. I guess it falls under "poetic license."</sub>

Here's the CSS rule that should be banished forever, or at least made to work correctly:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f6f6f6 1%, #f6f6f6 45%, #fff 45%, #fff 100%);
```

That means a solid-color "gradient" from the top to 45% down in an annoying shade of grey, and the rest white. It was intended to be a gradient, but then a mysterious `#f6f6f6 45%, #fff 45%,` appeared in the middle. Here's what you're looking for:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f6f6f6 1%, #fff 100%);
```

But why do you even need a background gradient/color The fact is that no avatar will blend in with that exact grey, whereas many avatars have a white background and will blend in nicely. So here's a much better CSS rule:

```
⁣
```

Comment: It kind of carries over the way they split the company logos on Careers

Comment: @random Did they split the company logos on Careers? I don't see that.

Comment: Also noted here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244242/162102

Comment: This is by design. This was not designed as a continual top to bottom gradient.

Comment: @Oded By what design? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @tbodt - are you saying that since it doesn't make sense to you it must have not been designed?

Comment: @Oded I want to know why it makes sense.

Comment: I don't really follow. The background was designed to be part grey part white. It was not designed as a continual gradient - which appear to be what you think it should be. Why should it be a gradient filling the container? Why does that make (more) sense?

Comment: @Oded Why was it designed to be part grey and part white?

Answer (score 5):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

It is hard to understand the beginning and end of About me, please border it or change the background color:

> [image]

Comment: This will look very strange on profiles with little content in the about me. Declining.

Comment: @Oded Then make it flex-height?

Answer (score 5):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - there is a link there, if there are more accounts than already visible.

On the old page ("Activity"), there was a list of a user's top accounts, and the word "Accounts" was a link to the accounts page of their network profile.

I noticed that on the new page ("Profile") the word was changed to "Communities," which is just fine IMO....but the word no longer links to a user's network profile.

This was useful to me if I saw a user, and thought I'd seen them before on another site in the network -- I could open their page and visually scan (or search, if there's too many accounts) for sites that I'm active on.
Since there's now no link on the default (Profile) page on MSE, if I want to do that, I have to switch to the other (Activity) page, which is way to much work!!! :(

All kidding aside; it's really no big deal, but I think this would be a nice change to implement. ( *can you call it a change when it's a request for things to remain the same?* )

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VlSd1.png

Comment: @nicael Hm.....you raise a good point. I'm not convinced that my proposed change is needed anymore.

Comment: Yeah, in general they're de-linking the section headers in favor of those "more..." links over on the right, so this is consistent with that.  I would much rather have the headers be links; I use those all the time because they're easier targets to hit; at smaller window sizes the "more" links in the right column are out of view and I have to scroll horizontally.  But even without that, the header is bigger and closer to the center of the page, so less mouse action and more-accurate clicking.

Comment: @Monica [It won't be implemented :(](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244308)

Comment: There is a link to the account page, if the users has more accounts than are displayed. This is seen in the screenshot from nicael.

Comment: These things are not gone - they just moved a bit.

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There's no way to see how much rep you have on other sites from the profile page.

On the Activity view, it shows me i have exactly 10,149 rep on SO; but the Profile view just shows 10.1k. (Same with other sites above 1k - it rounds.)

Hovering over it doesn't even give me the number! It just says the site name:

[image]

However, hovering over the badge icon does give me this *extremely* helpful tooltip:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (in the next build)

Old "Activity" tab counts my posts per tag well:

> [image]

But not the "Profile" tab:

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Personally I don't think that "Activity" is a good name for old part of user profile. Now we have two activity tabs by the way - one for old part of profile and another for all activity - posts, comments, badges received, etc. It could be confusing.

I think that the old name - "Dashboard" would be better. So please change the name of this tab, don't use "Activity".

Answer (score 4):

Um I guess this is [status-obsolete](/questions/tagged/status-obsolete)...

Well, if @Oded won't do it:

[image: If I don't like reality, at least I can script it]

[Download userscript here](https://gist.github.com/fredley/d63b2b9bb195d2b5494a/download), or [get the gist](https://gist.github.com/fredley/d63b2b9bb195d2b5494a).

**Update**

This script now actually shows your actual badge names. Working on the overlays on matching badges next...

Comment: Note that I dropped the `tt` parameter, in favor of keeping just one `tab` parameter (with values of `profile` and `allactivity` for the top tabs).

Comment: @Oded Noted! Latest version produces nice overlay of matching badges as you mouse over. Doesn't flow the overlay onto the last row of badges properly, still got that to fix...

Comment: @Oded But...but...the North Korean Generals!

Comment: Well... after what happened with Sony, we decided not to take any risks.

Answer (score 4):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

Whats up with diamonds in "Communities" section? They should be properly aligned.

> [image]

Comment: @Mari something wrong with my english?..

Comment: Nope, it's fine. Just saying, you can't please all of the people all of the time.

Comment: @Mari I just posted that because they are *usually* on the same line as the name and there they look like they are in superscript. You know it, don't you?

Comment: What browser/OS are you using? I can't reproduce this on latest Chrome, Windows 8.1

Answer (score 4):

Right now it looks like there might be a plan to allow for excluding sites from both the top network posts list, and communities list. However, I would hate for those to be the same list. I have 1 singular problem with my top post list:

[image: My issue with the top post list is only 1 question: Do Costume Affect Breast Physics]

It was a question that got quite a bit of attention (and was controversial) and so when I answered it, it got a lot of up votes. Frankly speaking, it isn't even a great answer. But it rose to the top pretty quickly and it now sits right on my profile.

Now I have no problem with the question at the end of the day (I did answer it, after all) but I do have a problem with it showing up on *every one of my profiles across the network*. My username here is part of my brand and I'd rather not have my brand be well known for it's "breast physics" expertise. Because when I am talking to a client or employer, they may not take well to that question.

On the other hand, I am a gamer, and my reputation on Arqade is the highest of any other community. Gaming is part of my identity and I have no problem with the other questions appearing there. And I actively **want** my Arqade reputation displayed on my communities list. It shows I know how to answer questions, and that I am knowledgeable and contribute to a community. The fact that it isn't Stack Overflow doesn't matter, it still builds my brand reputation to have that displayed.

So please, please, please let me just exclude a single question from my top posts list. And if that isn't going to be an option, then at least let me have a separate exclusion list for top posts and communities so that I can show off the good things I have done on that site.

Comment: I see where you're coming from with this, but it might be too much work (and lots of data to store).

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - we like eggs. But not that much. (with you in the next build)

"Top Rarest" in the badge display sounds odd. "Rarest" already implies most rare. "Top Rarest" is over-egging it a bit. Suggest just making it "Rarest".

Comment: Why not "Top X by rarity"?

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce - why not "Top X by rainbow-dash"?

Comment: @Oded Oh please. Top X by Pinkie Pie.

Comment: Seriously considering that.

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Eeek! The "Activity" tab only works when you're signed into the SE site. Repoed in Chrome and Firefox.

It works perfectly when signed in, but it won't change off the "Profile" tab when you're not signed in.

Comment: Reproduced (Firefox, private window).  That's bad; I look at profiles on sites where I don't have accounts, or don't want to sign in, fairly often, and it's the "activity" view I'm looking for.  (Example: looking at other activity from a user who's come to mod attention on sites I moderate.)

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

For some reason the "View all badges →" link in the Profile tab is broken when you view other user profile, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/144180/oli?tab=badges&tt=dashboard

It's just showing the tab as-is, while when clicked in my own profile, it shows the regular badges tab of the good old profile page.

Answer (score 2):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Why there is a line over the menus?

[image]

Comment: What browser and OS are you on?

Comment: @Oded Browser : Firefox version 28.0 . OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: This is not something that we will fix. It looks fine in current versions of FireFox - our [support policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) is for current and previous versions of popular browsers, and you are a few good versions behind. A a small visual glitch, we are not fixing this.

Answer (score 2):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

It would be great to have a link from "profile" tab directly to rep:

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

I think it is awesome! I like that it is already live on MSE and can't wait for it to hit primetime (SO).

It is very polished, contains a very small amount of nuance (people "helped"), and anything buggy or lacking going forward can likely be modified or brought up through feature-request, bug, or support posts.

If I had to make some suggestions though, here are some thoughts...

[image]

- <strike>Green: These should also be links to the total tags, or total posts (especially since the total number is included in the text already).</strike> [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - we won't add links here, as we already link to the relevant pages. Adding links will also alter the design, or if not, make non-obvious sections be linkable - we don't want either.
- <strike>Red: This text and section is inconsistent with the others. It shows the total count like they do, but it should probably be Total Badges.</strike> [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - the big difference here is that usually, we don't show a visualization of all tags or posts, but for badges, we do. If (when?) that changes, we will revisit the title.
- <strike>Blue: This area needs to be expanded. It should really be the entire section here, without the text notable, and with not only more badges but the link beneath to the post like the last one gets.</strike>[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), though we completely overhauled this section.
- <strike>Purple: Remove this please</strike> (see above)

Here is a suggested change, with an area where more badges could be placed.

[image]

Comment: About links: I noted about them in my answer which was declined and *deleted* by Oded...

Comment: re: "every element should fulfill only one purpose and that purpose should be visually clear" While this is good to do with things like buttons, links for titles are very different. Almost everything that is a title is a link online. Being consistent should be the design goal, and not following convention by incorporating behaviors from coding paradigms only harms user experience. Some examples already in production include the exchange logos, the question title, the user badge in posts, every heading in the classic profile, and every link which opens a modal.

Comment: @nicael - Sorry to hear that, but I do think your point was valid. I did not see your answer before posting this suggestion, but do note that this request is really focused on making sure the entire section is consistent and also provides a change to the type of content arrangement in the badge area.

Comment: @Oded - I like how you are modifying the proposals with status tags :) I think it makes the process more transparent.

Comment: @Oded - Thanks for the update :)

Comment: No problem ;) - the other bullets are WIP...

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - this was a bug. You will note that the `tt` param is now gone.

Feature-request: links like `https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/{id}/name?tab=...` should be redirected to `https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/{id}/name?tab=...&tt=activity`, because they became invalid. Not only in posts, but also in mobile web user page. It is now impossible to get a full list of answers, questions, tags, bounties, impossible to view reputation in mobile, [unless it is your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244391/259214). You will be thrown to full-site "Profile" tab. The only way would be to click "full site" in the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Tab "Profile" doesn't exist in mobile sites, maybe always use tab "Activity" in mobile view? Or any plans to implement "Profile" tab for mobile?

Comment: We are first focusing on getting the redesign out for desktop - once we are happy with these we will start looking at the mobile side.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Long display name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155074/?tab=profile) ruins the design:

> [image]

Comment: @Stéphane thanks, but I still see it cut off... guess it's waiting for a code deploy?

Comment: Yes, it will be live after our next production build

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

My superscripts aren't super enough:

[image: non-super scripts :(]

Answer (score 1):

[support](/questions/tagged/support) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - current site is excluded from the list.

MSE seems to be excluded from the Top Network Posts list. ([also](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244238/profile-page-makeover-part-3-the-prototype-returns/244256#244256))

I'm not sure whether this is an exception specific to MSE, or if it will always apply to the current site once the design is pushed network-wide.

Clarification on this would be nice.

Comment: It will always apply to the current site once the design is pushed network-wide.

Comment: Okay, cool. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

There is need for additional link to badges. Just link "Badges (x)". Same with top network posts and communities.

> [image]

Comment: I'm for clear UI and that means that every element should fulfill only one purpose and that purpose should be visually clear. Hence, think that the explicit links are good and necessary.

Answer (score 1):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - the spacing is consistent with other tabs in the site.

The space between the text and the underline hover decoration, seems awkwardly large. Can it be reduced?

[image]

*<sub>Thanks @Nicael for the better freehand!</sub>*

Comment: This is the same spacing that exists for the other tabs in other pages. Reducing it just here would be inconsistent with the other pages.

Comment: @Oded: Ok.. Not much of a problem anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This seems to be a new [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

> [image]

Where'd all my tops go???!!!?

Used to be:

> [image]

Also happens on other people's profiles.

Comment: Looks like when I excluded sites in private beta, live sites got excluded by mistake as well. Fixing.

Comment: @Oded My network profile is borked in the same way: http://stackexchange.com/users/2752900/bjb568?tab=top

Comment: @bjb568 No, that looks good. It includes the one from UX (graduated), and doesn't include ones from the site we're on (MSE).

Comment: @Scimonster It's missing Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact winter bash will soon be over (*wipes tears*), could this still count as a bug?

Badge icons under the avatar are located above the hatz:

> [image]
>
> [found in @Inf's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/245167/infinite-snowflakes), tested by me with different hatz

Comment: If anything, this should be a winterbash bug, given that once winterbash is over... the bug disappears.

Comment: @Oded [that's a bug again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271326/z-index-on-badge-icon-is-incorrect-with-hats-overlapping-it).

Answer (score 1):

The text in "top network posts" section of a user who doesn't have them is somewhat strange:

> [image]

([example user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/85949/john010117))

**Edit:** Oh, now I got the joke, misread it at first :D But this joke doesn't work well when the user has *no posts at all*.

Comment: I don't get the downvotes. Please explain.

Comment: I guess it is a boiler-plate text that could have said *No posts yet*. Instead it tries to be funny.

Comment: @rene ah, I got it :D

Comment: @nicael I did not downvote but I would guess the reason is "somewhat strange" is subjective. I actually like that text. Why did you feel it was strange and what do you think it should say?

Comment: @Jason I got the joke, did misread it a bit at first :D

Comment: Well, you know, if the joke is easy to misread or misunderstand then your "somewhat strange" claim probably holds some ground!

Comment: The choice of text is somewhat less than professional. Who are those "we"? Why don't they identify themselves, in particular when making a statement bordering on veiled insult (gee, look how narrow-minded this guy is)?

Comment: Try to remove it from the DOM. Then it really looks weird. So that is the reason for a boiler-plate text. We can now argue about the exact wording

Answer (score 0):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - this is mentioned in my post.

Its quite strange, but clicking link to own profile (from my answers, questions, comments) sends me to the "Activity" tab of my profile, while clicking a link to another user sends me to his "Profile" tab.

Comment: By design, as I said elsewhere.... delete?

Answer (score 0):

This issue now has a dedicated meta thread:

[We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/the-new-probably-shouldnt-be-called-people-helped-stat-input-needed)

---

The "Number of People Helped" statistic needs more transparency. If this goes into effect, then six months from now (let alone years from now), people will be seeing that number and wondering what the heck it means.

While it has been explained here and in other meta threads, these threads will be buried pretty soon, and users shouldn't have to go digging through meta (some don't even realize meta exists, let alone know how to search it) to find what an esoteric stat at the top of their profile page means.

At the very least, a tooltip that explains "This is the number of views your questions have, combined with the number of accepted answers, answers with score of 5 or higher [...]" would be very illuminating.

**Fewer clicks to find out what you want to know = success.**

Comment: Okay @Oded should [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244261/what-is-people-helped-and-why-does-it-exist-at-all/244455#244455) be where it is? Or should it be in the thread you added to the top of this answer?

Comment: Heh. Your answer there is aimed at that post, so I'd say belongs there. If you want to respond to the other thread - by all means, we are happy to get any and all feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Why tag badges are not included in "notable badges" section? I have two notable tag badges (both were awarded only 10 times). But "Informed" (awarded 15 times) is still shown as most notable.

Comment: Because tag badges got their own place maybe? (under Top Tags)

Comment: They are not excluded. But the criteria is not just how many were awarded, but also the class of the badge (gold > silver > bronze).

Answer (score 0):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)/[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

[Community ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) doesn't need to have "people reached" shown (I think so because he is a bot and he can't earn no achievements, e.g. rep, badges, etc).

> [image]

Or does it?...

Comment: Community also has 2 questions... this is an artifact of how some deletions work. These will get sorted out when a specific scheduled job runs.

Comment: Nor will we special case the page and design for the community user.

Comment: @Oded One second, Community *does* have 2 questions, nothing wrong with it...

Comment: And for those 2 questions, around 1k people were reached...

Answer (score 0):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - this is indeed by design. The year is shown about 11 months after the post was posted (when you don't see a year, that means it is the current/last year)

As far I can tell, any timestamp [in my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259214/nicael?tab=profile) lacks the year (Happy 2015! :D). Or the year will be added when a year since this timestamp was created pass?

Comment: @Oded Thanks, what about [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246530/259214)?

Answer (score 0):

In the Top Posts section, when I click between All / Questions / Answers or Votes / Newest, the underlines denoting the active options wiggle slightly, 1px right and left. I think it's to do with the loading animation nudging the layout.

Chrome (latest), Mac OSX.

Comment: Can't repro on latest Chrome Windows 7 :/

Comment: @Oded [Here's a gif](http://g.recordit.co/IBRSioiUP5.gif), it's very subtle.

Comment: Getting a 403 forbidden on that.

Comment: @Oded [Try this one](http://i.imgur.com/0xH5F80.gif)

Comment: Yeah, I see it, just can't repro. Possibly only OSX? Are you zoomed in at all?

Comment: @Oded Could be. No zoom, and no scripts/extensions running on the page.

Comment: @Oded I'm beginning to think this is a bug with Chrome, I can't stop it happening. [Here's a better gif showing what's going on](http://i.imgur.com/M8wFJTW.gif).

Answer (score -1):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Would be great to expand rep also, not only badges:

> [image]

Comment: There is a tooltip - hover over the rep.

Comment: @Oded Yes, I know :) but anyway, I'd like the rep to be fully expanded. It is not really hard to implement, plz?

Comment: @Oded and no tooltips if using phone. I personally prefer navigating in the full site.