# About impact measure

Tags: discussion, people-reached

From the beginning, [I liked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244586/268782) the impact measure (aka: people helped), but I must to [admit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244261/what-is-people-helped-and-why-does-it-exist-at-all/244408#244408) that my personal case is pretty much inexact. A shadow grows between the datetime of the question and my answers. My impact measure take in account views made before that I answered.

My SO profile show ~405k of impact, but my linear estimation is less of ~140k.

Here are two examples:

> [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490252/vertically-centering-a-div-inside-another-div): 1401 days from Q - 115k total views
>
> [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490252/vertically-centering-a-div-inside-another-div/25691157#25691157): 253  days from A - 20k estimated views (linear estimated)
>
> Difference: 95k views

---

> [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su/27134708): 523 days - 240k views
>
> [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su/27134708#27134708): 154 days - 70k views
>
> Difference: 170k views

---

> Total difference: ~405k - 95k - 170k = ~140k

So late answer should not be taken into account, or we need some kind of function to adjust this measure.

What do you think?

*Personally I won't lie to my grandma.*

Answer (score 6):

I suspect the problem here is technical: there is no record of views over time, only raw views counter.

So, to be able to fulfil your request first step should be change the code so that it starts recording when each view took place. However, with millions of views every day (hour?) it means consuming lots of resources, not to mention development time required to make it all work quickly.

All in all, I think the current way is fine. So you don't tell the whole truth so your granny, just an estimation - that's why they added a `~` in front of the value and clearly saying "**estimated** number".

Comment: Probably simpler to store number of views present at the time something was posted and subtract from current views to get reach.