# "Impact" metrics for new answers to old questions

Tags: feature-request, people-reached

I noticed this because of [this new answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/32504/5538) to a old question on Raspberry Pi Beta.  I was leaving a comment for the author, which I usually preface with "Welcome" if that person is new to the site.  To check that, I quickly glance at the user profile, which in this case included "Member since today" and other details making it clear this was the new member's first and only post.

Which is why I did a bit of a double take when it also said *~2k people reached.*  This seems very unlikely on a site where it may take a day just to get a few dozen views.

I realize that the total number of views on a Q&A is probably not stored indexed to time, so there is no definitive way to resolve this.  However, would it not make more sense to use a formula that includes some factoring of the original date on the question vs. the date of an answer?  A bit crude, but certainly more realistic than not.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254613/about-impact-measure (only discussion, not actually suggesting any change so not exact dupe)