# Where are my comments from the Activity tab?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, recent-activity

During the day I often click on my profile from the top bar and then click on the Activity tab to see comments that I made earlier in the day and follow up on those posts to see if anything happened.  It looks like the Activity tab is no longer there, but I can't see where I can find my list of comments that I made.

I see the Responses tab, but that only includes comments made to me, not comments that I made.

Where do I find them now?

Comment: Yeah, I feel that something is missing in my profile... Now I got it, it was activity tab!

Comment: Indeed, it has suddenly disappeared. That will make moderating... interesting.

Comment: Sorry about that - TIL, don't name a tab and subtab the same thing. Will be fixed in the next build.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aaand... it is back where it belongs: [Activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) > All actions > Comments.

Will be out in all network sites in a couple of minutes.

Sorry about that!

Comment: I see, now old profile's name All Activity :) Maybe its title should state it?

Comment: @nicael - no, still "Activity", but... yeah. Naming is hard ;)

Comment: If you need a site for Software QA so this doesn't happen again, I know [a good one](http://sqa.stackexchange.com)!!!

Comment: @corsiKa - thanks! Between MSE and MSO, I think we have it covered already ;)

Answer (score 5):

As you noticed, the whole activity tab disappeared, not just comments.

At least I know the reason *why* it did happen.

[This request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244392) was just implemented.

Before your old profile located at `/users/{id}/name?tt=activity` and your [new one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244238) located at `/users/{id}/name?tt=profile`. Your activity tab located at `/users/{id}/name?tt=activity&tab=activity` and (for example) reputation tab located at `/users/{id}/name?tt=activity&tab=reputation`.

Now, your new profile is located at `/users/{id}/name?tab=profile` and your old one is located at `/users/{id}/name?tab=activity` (notice that `tt` changed to `tab`). Your (for example) reputation tab is located at `/users/{id}/name?tab=reputation` and... where is located activity tab? With new change, it would be located at `/users/{id}/name?tab=activity`, but it is the url of old profile. So the tab activity just lost its url.

Either old profile section or the activity tab should be renamed. Because they both have name "Activity".

<sup><sup>[I knew that there will be confusion...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244454)</sup></sup>

Comment: Whoops. Fixing!