# User name shouldn't be scrolled with about me and should be separated from it

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

There should be a separator between the name and "About me'...

> [image]

And wut, the name is gone? Please ununite it with "about me" and place in another container.

> [image]

<sub>[and of course "about me" desperately wants The Borderzzzz](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244309), which was unfortunately declined :(</sub>