# Can the type and acceptance status of Top network posts be specified?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

In the new profile page, the type of the top posts on a user's given site is specified, i.e. whether the post is a question or an answer, and whether or not the user has accepted an answer for the question or has had their answer accepted.

Here, as an example, is part of my Meta profile.

[image]

On the left is the Top network posts section, which contains pretty much the same thing, but network-wide. This can be just as helpful as the site-specific Top Posts.

Can the same information (type of post and acceptance status, for lack of a better term) be added for the Top network posts?

---

Second related-but-not-as-important mini-request:

Can capitalization be standardized here? "Top Posts" has all words capitalized, but "Top network posts" does not.

Comment: A bit related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244256

Comment: @nicael I guess this is redundant, then.

Comment: Yours post isn't redutant, if that's what you implied. The answer I pointed is old and forgotten :)

Comment: @nicael I actually had meant that. What's the benefit of the same thing being posted twice? I guess putting it as a question could help.

Comment: That thread was just a feedback page for a while, guess its not active now. But you can mark yours as dupe if you want.