# z-index on badge icon is incorrect with hats overlapping it

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, design, winter-bash-2015

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVKR2.png]

See that image above. The hat comes out of the gravatar and overlaps the badge count. What should happen is that the hat should cover the badges. However, it doesn't cover the badge icon. Now the husky has 2 buttons on his shirt.

This is what it should look like:

[image]

Comment: Heh, I've [reported this last year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246530) :)

Comment: @nicael oh lol, was searching under [winterbash-2015]. No wonder I didn't see it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taco no longer has buttons. I'll send him your way if he complains about being cold.